# Problem with loop to add values from one dataframe and to another based on conditions

Tags: r, loops

In R, I have two dataframes. The first is called `d` and looks like this:

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(384923059L, 384923060L, 384923061L, 386269528L
), decimalLatitude = c(46.08, 48.73333, 46.35, 58.16), decimalLongitude = c(-55.40333, 
-52.96667, -52.73333, -61.088), datecollected = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2015-08-20 12:00:00+02", "2015-11-19 12:00:00+01", 
"2015-11-27 12:00:00+01"), class = "factor"), institutioncode = c("ARC", 
"ARC", "ARC", "DFOCENARC"), individualcount = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), depth = c(93, 95, 166, 216), resname = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Atlantic Reference Centre Museum of Canadian Atlantic Organisms - Invertebrates and Fishes Data", 
"DFO Central and Arctic Multi-species Stock Assessment Surveys"
), class = "factor"), originalscientificname = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Mallotus villosus", class = "factor"), 
    collectioncode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("ARC", 
    "DFOSurvey_Modified Standard (14\") Campelen"), class = "factor"), 
    year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), month = c(11, 11, 11, 8
    ), day = c(19, 27, 19, 20)), row.names = c(7216L, 7217L, 
7218L, 11980L), class = "data.frame")
```

str(d) reveals

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ layer_name: num  0.506 1.556 2.668 3.856 5.14 ...
 $ raw_min   : num  0 1.03 2.11 3.26 4.5 ...
 $ raw_max   : num  1.03 2.11 3.26 4.5 5.84 ...
 $ bin_min   : int  0 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 11 13 ...
 $ bin_max   : int  0 1 2 4 5 6 8 10 12 15 ...
 $ layer_no  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The second dataframe is called `c`

```
c <- structure(list(layer_name = c(0.505760014, 1.55585527, 2.66768169, 
3.85627985, 5.14036131, 6.5430336, 8.09251881, 9.82275009, 11.7736797, 
13.9910383, 16.525322, 19.4298019, 22.757616, 26.5583, 30.8745613, 
35.7402039, 41.1800232, 47.211895, 53.8506355, 61.1128387, 69.0216827, 
77.6111603, 86.9294281, 97.0413132, 108.030281, 120, 133.075821, 
147.40625, 163.164459, 180.549927, 199.789963, 221.141174, 244.890625, 
271.356384, 300.887512, 333.862823, 370.688477, 411.793854, 457.62561, 
508.639893, 565.292297, 628.026001, 697.258667, 773.368286, 856.678955, 
947.447876, 1045.85425, 1151.99121, 1265.86145, 1387.37695), 
    raw_min = c(0, 1.030807642, 2.11176848, 3.26198077, 4.49832058, 
    5.841697455, 7.317776205, 8.95763445, 10.7982149, 12.882359, 
    15.25818015, 17.97756195, 21.09370895, 24.657958, 28.71643065, 
    33.3073826, 38.46011355, 44.1959591, 50.53126525, 57.4817371, 
    65.0672607, 73.3164215, 82.2702942, 91.98537065, 102.5357971, 
    114.0151405, 126.5379105, 140.2410355, 155.2853545, 171.857193, 
    190.169945, 210.4655685, 233.0158995, 258.1235045, 286.121948, 
    317.3751675, 352.27565, 391.2411655, 434.709732, 483.1327515, 
    536.966095, 596.659149, 662.642334, 735.3134765, 815.0236205, 
    902.0634155, 996.651063, 1098.92273, 1208.92633, 1326.6192
    ), raw_max = c(1.030807642, 2.11176848, 3.26198077, 4.49832058, 
    5.841697455, 7.317776205, 8.95763445, 10.7982149, 12.882359, 
    15.25818015, 17.97756195, 21.09370895, 24.657958, 28.71643065, 
    33.3073826, 38.46011355, 44.1959591, 50.53126525, 57.4817371, 
    65.0672607, 73.3164215, 82.2702942, 91.98537065, 102.5357971, 
    114.0151405, 126.5379105, 140.2410355, 155.2853545, 171.857193, 
    190.169945, 210.4655685, 233.0158995, 258.1235045, 286.121948, 
    317.3751675, 352.27565, 391.2411655, 434.709732, 483.1327515, 
    536.966095, 596.659149, 662.642334, 735.3134765, 815.0236205, 
    902.0634155, 996.651063, 1098.92273, 1208.92633, 1326.6192, 
    1387), bin_min = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 
    16L, 18L, 21L, 25L, 29L, 33L, 39L, 44L, 51L, 58L, 65L, 73L, 
    82L, 92L, 103L, 114L, 127L, 140L, 155L, 172L, 190L, 211L, 
    233L, 258L, 286L, 317L, 352L, 391L, 435L, 483L, 537L, 597L, 
    663L, 735L, 815L, 902L, 997L, 1099L, 1209L, 1327L), bin_max = c(0L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 17L, 20L, 24L, 28L, 
    32L, 38L, 43L, 50L, 57L, 64L, 72L, 81L, 91L, 102L, 113L, 
    126L, 139L, 154L, 171L, 189L, 210L, 232L, 257L, 285L, 316L, 
    351L, 390L, 434L, 482L, 536L, 596L, 662L, 734L, 814L, 901L, 
    996L, 1098L, 1208L, 1326L, 1387L), layer_no = 1:50), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

str(c) reveals

```
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ id                    : int  384923059 384923060 384923061 386269528 386270555 386270577 386270682 386272010 386272026 386272096 ...
 $ decimalLatitude       : num  46.1 48.7 46.4 58.2 61.6 ...
 $ decimalLongitude      : num  -55.4 -53 -52.7 -61.1 -69.7 ...
 $ datecollected         : Factor w/ 13219 levels "","1854-07-02 12:00:00+00:17:30",..: 13218 13219 13218 13208 13209 13209 13210 13211 13212 13212 ...
 $ institutioncode       : chr  "ARC" "ARC" "ARC" "DFOCENARC" ...
 $ individualcount       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ depth                 : num  93 95 166 216 289 227 149 223 440 451 ...
 $ resname               : Factor w/ 39 levels "Arctic Marine Fish Museum Specimens",..: 3 3 3 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 ...
 $ originalscientificname: Factor w/ 2 levels "Mallotus catervarius",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ collectioncode        : Factor w/ 98 levels "","12.190","14.102",..: 35 35 35 59 58 58 58 58 58 58 ...
 $ year                  : num  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ month                 : num  11 11 11 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 ...
 $ day                   : num  19 27 19 20 28 28 29 9 10 10 ...
```

I would like to do is for each row in d, find where `d$depth` is `>= c$binmin & < c$binmax`, and then add the corresponding value in `c$layer_name` to `d$depth_layer`. Where `d$depth == NA`, `d$depthlayer` would also `== NA`

In the example dataframes above, the resulting dataframe `d` would look like this:

```
id  depth   depth_layer
1   1       1.55585527
2   5       5.14036131
3   NA      NA
4   6       6.5430336
5   3       3.85627985
```

I have tried to create a `for` loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if (d$depth[i] >= c$bin_min & d$depth[i] <= c$bin_max) {
      d$depth_layer[i] <- c$layer_name
    } else {
      d$depth_layer[i] <- NA
    }
}
```

but it gave the following error:

```
�>=� not meaningful for factors�<=� not meaningful for factorsthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedError in if (d$depth[i] >= c$bin_min & d$depth[i] <=  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I'm not sure how to fix the loop. Any help is gratefully received.

ADDITIONAL

As pointed out by @forestfanjoe in the comments, one of my variables (`d$depth`) was a factor. After changing this to numeric (`as.numeric`) both @forestfanjoe and @TinglTanglBob solutions worked.

Comment: The error message suggests that one of your variables is a factor, rather than numeric. Could you add the output from `str(c)` and `str(d)`? Also if you add `dput(c)` and `dput(d)`, this will make your question more easily reproducible.

Comment: @forestfanjoe - you are absolutely right about the factor. `str(d)` revealed that `d$depth` is the culprit. I should have thought about this... thanks for pointing it out nicely.

Once I changed `d$depth` to `as.numeric`, both your and @TinglTanglBob solutions worked. I'll add the `str` and the `dput` for both original dataframes (rather than the cut-down versions I made to ask the question) to the post  - it may help others who stumble across this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
d <- data.frame("id" = c(1:5), "depth" = c(1, 5, NA, 6, 3))

c <- data.frame(matrix(data = c(
0,        0,        1,         0.505760014,
1,        1,        2,         1.55585527,
2,        2,        3,         2.66768169,
3,        4,        4,         3.85627985,
5,        5,        5,         5.14036131,
6,        6,       6,         6.5430336,
7,        8,        7,         8.09251881), ncol = 4, byrow = T))
names(c) <- c("bin_min", "bin_max", "layer_no", "layer_name")

check_depth <- function(d_temp)
{
  print(d_temp)
  if(is.na(d_temp)) return(NA) # if d_temp is na just return NA 
  layer_name_temp <- c$layer_name[which(c$bin_min <= d_temp & c$bin_max >= d_temp)]
  if(length(layer_name_temp) > 1) layer_name_temp <- layer_name_temp[1] # in case there are more hits, the first one is taken
  return(layer_name_temp)
}


d$depth_layer <- sapply(d$depth, check_depth)

d
```

output for d

```
> d
  id depth depth_layer
1  1     1    1.555855
2  2     5    5.140361
3  3    NA          NA
4  4     6    6.543034
5  5     3    3.856280
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to TinglTanglBob's solution:

```
d <- read.table(
text = 
"
id  depth
1   1
2   5
3   NA
4   6
5   3
", header = T)

c <- read.table(
text = "
bin_min  bin_max  layer_no  layer_name
0        0        1         0.505760014
1        1        2         1.55585527
2        2        3         2.66768169
3        4        4         3.85627985
5        5        5         5.14036131
6        6        6         6.5430336
7        8        7         8.09251881                
", header = T)
```

If you need this to be a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(d)){
    if(!is.na(d$depth[i])) {
        rw <- which(d$depth[i] >= c$bin_min & d$depth[i] <= c$bin_max)
        d$depth_layer[i] <- c$layer_name[rw]

    } else {
        d$depth_layer[i] <- NA 
    }
}
```

You could also try vapply:

```
d$depth_layer <- vapply(d$depth, 
       function(x) {
           if(is.na(x)) return(NA)
           rw <- which(x >= c$bin_min & x <= c$bin_max)
           c$layer_name[rw]
           }, 0)
```